# How to start Python file (filename.py, which have appeal to oracle ) from sikuli?

Tags: python, oracle, jython, sikuli

I tried to import os, then import my module..
[error] ImportError ( No module named filename )

Comment: Please give more information. This isn't nearly enough for someone to replicate the issue. Directory structure along with the verbatim `import` statements in the failing python file would be useful!

Comment: Perhaps this can help: https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/286612

Answer (score 0):

If I take your question quite literal, this would do it:

```
run("C:\Path\To\Python\python.exe C:\Path\To\Script\script.py")
```

This would require Python to be installed in `C:\Path\To\Python\`.

If you want to import the python script this only works if the Python code is supported by Sikuli's Jython interpreter. Instructions on how to proceed are [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+faq/1114).

Reference:
https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+faq/1114